# Customize tabular with tikz: extract width of a column

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, width

Currently I use this custom type of tabular (with packages `tikz`, `booktabs`, `etoolbox`):

```
\def\head#1\\{\shead#1&\\}
\def\shead#1&#2\\{\color{white}#1\ifstrempty{#2}{\\}{&\shead#2\\}}

\newsavebox{\dataTableContent} % Box
\newenvironment{dataTable}[1] % \new environment
{%
\begin{lrbox}{\dataTableContent}%
\begin{tabular}{#1}\head}%
%
{%
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [inner xsep=0pt] (tbl){\usebox{\dataTableContent}};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    % table
    \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!1,bottom color=gray!30,draw=black](tbl.north east) rectangle (tbl.south west);
    % top line
    \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!10!black,bottom color=gray!50!black,draw=black]%
    ($(tbl.north west)$) rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0,1.5\baselineskip)$);
    % bottom rule
    \draw[rounded corners=0.25pt,fill=gray,draw=black]%
    (tbl.south west) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)+(0,0)$);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

This environment works very well. But now, I want to do the same with column (for having black column with with text for the first column). How can I do this? This seems to be more complicated due to the fact that I need the width of the first column (which depends of the length of the words inside it).

So my question is: how can I obtain the width of one row automatically without specify manually it).

**MWE:**

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc} 
 \usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox}
 \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
 \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

    \def\head#1\\{\shead#1&\\}
     \def\shead#1&#2\\{\color{white}#1\ifstrempty{#2}{\\}{&\shead#2\\}}

     \newsavebox{\dataTableContent} % Box
     \newenvironment{dataTable}[1] % \new environment
     {%
     \begin{lrbox}{\dataTableContent}%
     \begin{tabular}{#1}\head}%
     %
     {%
     \end{tabular}
     \end{lrbox}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node [inner xsep=0pt] (tbl){\usebox{\dataTableContent}};
       \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
         % table
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!1,bottom color=gray!30,draw=black](tbl.north east) rectangle (tbl.south west);
         % top line
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!10!black,bottom color=gray!50!black,draw=black]%
         ($(tbl.north west)$) rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0,1.5\baselineskip)$);
         % bottom rule
         \draw[rounded corners=0.25pt,fill=gray,draw=black]%
         (tbl.south west) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)+(0,0)$);
       \end{pgfonlayer}
     \end{tikzpicture}}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{dataTable}{lcc} et&Rien&tout\\\midrule ou&si&non
 \end{dataTable}

 \end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

**Solution (based on proposal below):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes,backgrounds,matrix}
%preview tikzpicture
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

%for checked and unchecked symbols
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\color{green!50!black}\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\color{red}\ding{55}}%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{dataTableV}[2] % \new environment
{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\nbRow {#2}
\def\nbCol {#1}
 \matrix (m) [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={minimum height=2em,text width=2cm,align=center, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt},
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column 1/.style={align=left,text = white},
      ]}{;\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
         % table
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!1,bottom color=gray!30,draw=black]
               (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-\nbRow-\nbCol.south east);
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!10!black,
              bottom color=gray!80!black,draw=black] (m-1-1.north west) rectangle
                  (m-\nbRow-1.south east); 

       \end{pgfonlayer}
       \end{tikzpicture}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{dataTableVH}[2] % \new environment
{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \newcommand*{\nbRow}{#2}%
 \newcommand*{\nbCol}{#1}%
\newcommand*{\ColorGradT}{10}%
\newcommand*{\ColorGradB}{80}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ColorVO}{\ColorGradT}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ColorP}{(\ColorGradB-\ColorVO)/\nbRow}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ColorGradM}{\ColorP*1+\ColorVO}%
   \matrix (m) [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={minimum height=2em,text width=2cm,align=center, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt},
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column 1/.style={align=left,text = white},
      row 1/.style={align=left,text = white},
      ]}{;\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
         % table
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!1,bottom color=gray!30,draw=black] (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-\nbRow-\nbCol.south east);         
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!\ColorGradT!black,bottom color=gray!\ColorGradB!black,draw=black] (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-\nbRow-1.south east); 
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!\ColorGradT!black,bottom color=gray!\ColorGradM!black,draw=none] (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-1-\nbCol.south east);

       \end{pgfonlayer} 
       \end{tikzpicture}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}
\begin{dataTableVH}{6}{6}{|[align=left]|&Face Plane&Sphère&Cylindre&Cône&Cercle\\
|[align=left]|Face Plane&\cmark&\cmark&\cmark&\xmark&\xmark\\
|[align=left]|Sphère&\cmark&\cmark&\xmark&\xmark&\xmark\\
|[align=left]|Cylindre&\cmark&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark&\xmark\\
|[align=left]|Cône&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark&\cmark&\cmark\\
|[align=left]|Cercle&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark\\
} 
\end{dataTableVH}
\begin{dataTableV}{6}{5}{
|[align=left]|Face Plane&\cmark&\cmark&\cmark&\xmark&\xmark\\
|[align=left]|Sphère&\cmark&\cmark&\xmark&\xmark&\xmark\\
|[align=left]|Cylindre&\cmark&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark&\xmark\\
|[align=left]|Cône&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark&\cmark&\cmark\\
|[align=left]|Cercle&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark&\cmark&\xmark\\} 
\end{dataTableV}
\end{document}
```

**Results:**
[image: Res1]
[image: Res2]

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to use colortbl?  I can't find the source for tabular, but the widths were probably lost at the \endgroup.

Comment: Maybe but I don't kwon if I can have the same kind of color gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an idea on which you have to build. I feel that you will be better off using `colortbl` as suggested by John. But if you want gradients etc, you may use `matrix` from `tikz`

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,matrix}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix (m) [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={minimum height=2em,text width=2cm,align=center, anchor=center, outer sep=0pt},
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column 1/.style={nodes={align=left,text = white}},
      ]
{
  et & Rien & tout\\
  ou & si   & non\\
};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
         % table
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!1,bottom color=gray!30,draw=black]
               (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-2-3.south east);
         \draw[rounded corners=1pt,rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!10!black,
              bottom color=gray!80!black,draw=black] (m-1-1.north west) rectangle
                  (m-2-1.south east);

       \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}


 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you lose the text width and align=center from the nodes=[] are and replace it with column 1/.style={align=base left}, column2/.style={align=base},column 3/.style={align=base east} it will be more like the original tabular.

Comment: Thank you. I propose in my post a modified version of your solution.